# How can one overload function without using any?

Tags: typescript

How can one overload `set` function without using `any`?

```js
import store from "electron-store"

interface Store {
  challenge: string
  response: string
  yubikeys: string[]
}

const config = new store<Store>({
  schema: schema
})

function set(object: Partial<Store>): void
function set<Key extends keyof Store>(key: Key, value: Store[Key]): void
function set(objectOrKey: any, value?: any): void {
  if (value !== undefined) {
    return config.set(objectOrKey, value)
  } else {
    return config.set(objectOrKey)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Might have figured it out but want to make sure following is best practice.

```js
function set(object: Partial<Store>): void
function set<Key extends keyof Store>(key: Key, value: Store[Key]): void
function set<Key extends keyof Store>(
  objectOrKey: Partial<Store> | Key,
  value?: Store[Key]
): void {
  if (typeof objectOrKey === "object") {
    return config.set(objectOrKey)
  } else {
    return config.set(objectOrKey, value)
  }
}
```

Comment: "Best practice" is subjective but I would create a class with 2 methods `setKey` and `setObject` since you are actually maintaining state, instead of having one complex function which changes behaviour based on what you pass to it and runs side-effects. It's going to be easier to use and easier to maintain.

Comment: This is correct; ideally the function declaration should have some sort of combination of the overloads as the signature.